# .Net 1.1 C# Development on 64bit Vista with IIS 7.0 and Vs2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, 64-bit, .net-1.1

Can this be made to work? - been having lots of issues setting it up:

HttpHandlers not being seen even though .net 1.1 is installed and regiis -i working, worker processes crashing.

Really need this for maintaining many old projects.

Is there a specific order that things need to be installed in?

Comment: This was one of the challenging things for me to get setup as well, and we ended up just upgrading to .Net 2.0 to avoid future issues with server hosting and development environments

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my .NET 1.1 applications working in IIS 7 on Vista 64bit without having any issues. To get everything working properly, you have to create a special application pool in IIS dedicated to .NET 1.1.

You also need to disable data execution prevention if you want to debug your applications. Here are the instructions for doing that:

[Disabling Data Execution Prevention (DEP)](http://www.realtime-vista.com/administration/2007/04/disabling_data_execution_preve.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not support Visual Studio 2003 on Vista anymore, no matter whether 32bit or 64bit version. See the [Visual Studio on Vista FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa948854.aspx) and the list of [known issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb188244.aspx).

This means even if everything seems to work there might be unexpected problems. If a direct upgrade to .NET 2.0 (or greater) is not an option I would use a development VM with the older VS version to maintain the .NET 1.1 projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least upgrade to .NET 1.1 SP1, even if you don't care about running a supported configuration.

Answer (score 0):

man seriously, if it will take some work but you can do it, then upgrade to .Net 2, you will save your self a lot of fuss, if you cant then as John suggested at least upgrade to 1.1 SP1.

also if i was in your position i would use Vmware to run xp and IIS 6 on it, other that i think you are going to face a lot of problems, all the best for you